# Does git use sh? If so can it be changed to use bash?

Tags: git, bash, cygwin, sh

When I run a git command I often get

```
sh: line 0: igncr: invalid option name
```

As output. This is caused by a setting I have to make cygwin tolerable. IT looks like git is spawning a sh process to run in. Can I configure this to be a bash shell instead?

It doesn't add much but as requested here is the git command

```
gt ad -p A/B/C.csproj
```

The shell commands causing failure are

```
export SHELLOPTS
set -o igncr
```

If run with GIT_TRACE=1

```
trace: exec: 'git-ad' '-p' 'A/B/C.csproj'
trace: run_command: 'git-ad' '-p' 'A/B/C.csproj'
trace: alias expansion: ad => 'add'
trace: built-in: git 'add' '-p' 'A/B/C.csproj'
trace: run_command: 'add--interactive' '--patch' '--' 'A/B/C.csproj'
trace: exec: 'git-add--interactive' '--patch' '--' 'A/B/C.csproj'
trace: run_command: 'git-add--interactive' '--patch' '--' 'A/B/C.csproj'
trace: built-in: git 'rev-parse' '--show-prefix'
trace: built-in: git 'config' '--get-colorbool' 'color.interactive' 'false'
trace: built-in: git 'config' '--get-color' 'color.interactive.prompt' 'bold blu                      e'
trace: built-in: git 'config' '--get-color' 'color.interactive.header' 'bold'
trace: built-in: git 'config' '--get-color' 'color.interactive.help' 'red bold'
trace: built-in: git 'config' '--get' 'color.interactive.help'
trace: built-in: git 'config' '--get-color' 'color.interactive.error' 'red bold'
trace: built-in: git 'config' '--get-colorbool' 'color.diff' 'false'
trace: built-in: git 'config' '--get-color' 'color.diff.frag' 'cyan'
trace: built-in: git 'config' '--get-color' 'color.diff.plain' ''
trace: built-in: git 'config' '--get-color' 'color.diff.old' 'red'
trace: built-in: git 'config' '--get-color' 'color.diff.new' 'green'
trace: built-in: git 'config' '--get-color' '' 'reset'
trace: built-in: git 'config' '--bool' '--get' 'interactive.singlekey'
trace: built-in: git 'rev-parse' '--git-dir'
trace: built-in: git 'update-index' '--refresh'
trace: built-in: git 'ls-files' '--' 'A/B/C.csproj'
sh: line 0: igncr: invalid option name
trace: built-in: git 'diff-index' '--cached' '--numstat' '--summary' 'HEAD' '--' 'A/B/C.csproj'
trace: built-in: git 'diff-files' '--numstat' '--summary' '--raw' '--' 'A/B/C.csproj'
trace: built-in: git 'diff-files' '-p' '--' 'A/B/C.csproj'
trace: built-in: git 'diff-files' '-p' '--color' '--' 'A/B/C.csproj'
```

Comment: Please post your git command

Comment: It's likely due to a custom command that specifies the interpreter as `sh`.

Comment: What does `echo $SHELL` show?  If it says `/bin/sh` instead of `/bin/bash`, that may be the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please run the failing git command prefixed with `GIT_TRACE=1` to see the details of the failing shell command spawned, and take it from there...

EDIT: After seeing the trace, given the fact that igncr is a cygwin specific bash option, consider adding a bash function to override the `gt` command and turn off that shell option.

For example,

```
gt () { (set +o igncr; git "$@";) }
gt ls-files
```

of course you should move the `gt` function to your .bashrc or similar.

Comment: Can you please post the result of `GIT_TRACE=1 gt ad -p A/B/C.csproj` ?

Comment: I don't understand what this means. If you mean with a semi-colon then it achievs nothing / makes no diference

Comment: @devnull The OP is not sure what's causing the problem, and this is what I get the crux of the question. Has nothing to do with bash. The answer advises of a swiss-knife setting that is applicable to this situation.

Comment: @James Robinson I think devnull was saying that the answer is not an answer but rather a comment, which maybe can be interpreted as such, though I don't think so. In any case, please run the command verbatim and try to see in the debugging lines what is git invoking to cause the problem. You can post the trace lines here as well of course.

Comment: @devnull my apologies I did not know that you could but such variable setting without a semi-colon

Comment: Seems I was wrong about this not having anything to do with bash. The `git ls-files` builtin uses shell globbing, and igncr is very much a cygwin specific setting.

Comment: @mockinterface, this function can be more "transparent": `git() (set +o igncr; command git "$@")` -- the outer braces are not needed if parentheses are used to create a subshell anyway. And parentheses do not require the list to be terminated with a semicolon. Ah bash, your adorable inconsistencies.

Comment: @glennjackman You are right of course, but it'd likely be detrimental to confuse the readers with the more advance bash concepts such as a function without the outer braces - I think it's clearer to everyone when it's like this. The last semicolon is iffy though, but still probably more readable.

Comment: @glennjackman: even plain old `sh` (well, the newfangled POSIX sh anyway) accepts the `f() (cmds)` syntax. Can't blame that particular one on bash.  (There's plenty one *can* of course... :-) )